# Selecting different portions of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to retrieve the different portions of the below dataframe based on the condition LabelId=1. In other words, given the following dataframe:

DF_input:

```
   eventTime                 velocity     LabelId
1  2017-08-19 12:53:55.050         3        0
2  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
3  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150       180        1
4  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
5  2017-08-19 12:53:55.250         5        0
6  2017-08-19 12:53:55.050         3        0
7  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
8  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150        70        1
9  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
10 2017-08-19 12:53:55.250         5        0
```

DF_output1

```
   eventTime                 velocity     LabelId 
2  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
3  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150       180        1
4  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
```

DF_output_2

```
eventTime                 velocity     LabelId
7  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
8  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150        70        1
9  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
```

My attempt was using the condition DF_input["LabelId"] == 1 but it returns all the rows in one dataframe. So I cannot distinguish between the two subset.

Comment: I think that the only way to do this would be by looping over it.

Comment: @lorenzori you very rarely should or even need to loop over a dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
l=[ None if df1[df1.LabelId==1].empty  else df1[df1.LabelId==1] for _, df1 in df.groupby(df.LabelId.eq(0).cumsum())]
l
Out[402]: 
[                eventTime  velocity  LabelId
 2  2017-08-1912:53:55.100         4        1
 3  2017-08-1912:53:55.150       180        1
 4  2017-08-1912:53:55.200         2        1,
 None,
                 eventTime  velocity  LabelId
 7  2017-08-1912:53:55.100         4        1
 8  2017-08-1912:53:55.150        70        1
 9  2017-08-1912:53:55.200         2        1,
 None]
```

New group key detail

```
df.LabelId.eq(0).cumsum()
Out[398]: 
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     3
10    4
Name: LabelId, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am checking it. But what is df? df1?

Comment: @CarloAllocca df is your DF_input, df1 is sub dataframe after groupby

Comment: I see. Why do I need "New group key detail " ?

Comment: Moreover, there are "None" elements in l. How to get rid of them?

Comment: I see. What about the None, should I add an extra test if it is not None?

Comment: @CarloAllocca you can filter it out by `[x for x in l if x is not None]`

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if not a big dataframe you can do something simple like:

```
portion = []
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[ix - 1, 'Labelid']==0 and row['Labelid']==0: 
        portion.append(row)
    else:
        # do stuff on the portion
    portion = []
```

Comment: the dataframe could be 15 Mega big. Is this OK in size?

Comment: I don't know how many rows that is but if we are talking 100s of thousands or more be ready to wait. But you can always do some other things in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, but a bit messy.

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

acc = np.cumsum([len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(df['LabelId'])])

i = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(acc, acc[1:])][::2]

dfs = [df.iloc[m:n, :] for m, n in i]

# [   velocity  LabelId
# 1         4        1
# 2       180        1
# 3         2        1,
#     velocity  LabelId
# 6         4        1
# 7        70        1
# 8         2        1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops, just some tricky logic with cumulative sums:

```
from io import StringIO

import numpy
import pandas

data = StringIO("""\
eventTime                 velocity     LabelId
2017-08-19 12:53:55.050         3        0
2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
2017-08-19 12:53:55.150       180        1
2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
2017-08-19 12:53:55.250         5        0
2017-08-19 12:53:55.050         3        0
2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
2017-08-19 12:53:55.150        70        1
2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
2017-08-19 12:53:55.250         5        0
""")

df = (
    pandas.read_table(data, sep='\s\s+')
        .assign(diff=lambda df: df['LabelId'].diff())
        .assign(group=lambda df: numpy.where(
            (df['diff'] == 1).cumsum() == (df['diff'].shift(-1) == -1).shift(1).cumsum(),
            0,
            (df['diff'] == 1).cumsum()
        ))
        .query("group > 0")
        .drop(columns='diff')
)
```

And then with e.g.,

```
print(df[df['group'] == 1])
```

you get:

```
                 eventTime  velocity  LabelId  group
1  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1      1
2  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150       180        1      1
3  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1      1
```